# How to filter pluggable function from wordpress child-theme

Tags: wordpress, function, filter, themes, pluggable

I need to add a filter to a specific wordpress function which is defined in a file which is included by a pluggable function theme's functions f

functions.php:

```
if (!function_exists('nectar_colors_css_output')) {
    function nectar_colors_css_output(){
        include('css/colors.php');
    }
}
```

colors.php:

```
<?php 
function nectar_colors() {
    // not relevant what happens here, but I have 
    // to call another function before this one is called!
}
?>
```

I use a child theme and when I try to filter this function from the child theme's functions.php, nothing happens. This is because pluggable functions of the parent theme will be called **after** calling the filters from the child theme.

My filter function in the child theme's functions.php is

```
function filter_function() {
  // some custom actions...
}
add_filter('nectar_colors', 'filter_function');
```

How can I get this filter working?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to filter on? You might be misunderstanding the concepts.

Take your example provided. The parent checks if a function exists before creating it. 
So basically, if you define it in your child's theme, the parent will know it's there and won't create a default one.

```
#themename-child

function nectar_colors_css_output(){
    error_log("It worked!");
}
```

Comment: That would be a solution, but it's a bit more complicated:

The pluggable parent theme function includes another php script, which contains the function I need to filter. 

I need a solution which calls the parent theme function before the filter of my child is used.

I could remove the if `(!function_exists('nectar_colors_css_output')) {`
but I don't want to change the parent theme's files!

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I changed the question :)

Comment: Sorry for this, but I still can't quite understand what you are trying to do. I understood you can't modify the parent theme code? In that case you can only use "hooks" they provided. Look for `do_action()` or `apply_filter()`.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to modify the parent theme code. The problem is that the hook does not work for functions which are included  (defined) after the filter is defined.

Comment: Can you please provide the actual code where this happens? It would help a lot.

Comment: I changed the question a bit, now it contains the actual code. I removed the method bodies because they are more than 200 lines long ;)
Please try to reconstruct my problem with the actual code and you will see that the filter is not working.